# mysql - best way to provide unique voucher

Tags: mysql, php

I am designing a website that will provide vouchers (serial codes). All voucher codes generated and saved in a table like this and not generated online:

```
 v_id             voucher                status (used?)
-------------------------------------------------------
  1              abcdefgabcdefg1             0
  2              abcdefgabcdefg2             0
  3              abcdefgabcdefg3             0
  4              abcdefgabcdefg4             0
```

I should display unused (status:0) voucher to end user after successful payment but I am not sure how can I do this because this site may have high traffic so more than one people may visit site in same milisecond of time, so for example I can not just use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=0 LIMIT 0,1;
```

and then UPDATE it:

```
UPDATE table SET status=1 WHERE v_id=....
```

because two people may visit in same time so we provide same serial code in SELECT before we UPDATE.

what would be best way to ensure I display unique serial code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to update and select in the same statement; and add a condition to the statement so that (if selected, don't select again)

Here is my way:

```
SET @voucher_id=0;
UPDATE voucher_table SET status=1, v_id = (SELECT @voucher_id := v_id) WHERE status=0 LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM voucher_table WHERE v_id=@voucher_id;
```

It is kind of creating an artificial lock. Notice that any other transaction (or user) won't be able to pick up the same voucher ID due to the **A**tomicity and **I**solation in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties of the database systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky 'function' that can help here:

```
UPDATE voucher_table
    SET status = 1,
        v_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(v_id)
    WHERE status = 0
    LIMIT 1;
```

Now LAST_INSERT_ID() contains the v_id, and is session-specific.  That is, no chance of another connection picking it up.  So then

```
SELECT * FROM voucher_table
    WHERE v_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```